# Azure Function slot swap terminates all currently running processes

Tags: azure, azure-functions

### Current Issue

I am currently working on a prototype to implement function slots for an in-process function running on a Windows app service plan with a service bus trigger. The issue is that as soon as I swap slots, all currently running processes are terminated. The problem with that is that we cannot have any retries in our production scenario and so the currently running processes need to finish first. The real thing has some durable functions as well which should also continue running.

Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

### Bicep:

```
resource function 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    alwaysOn: true
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
  }
}

module appSettings 'appendAppSettings.bicep' = {
  name: 'appSettings'
  params: {
    currentAppSettings: list('${function.id}/config/appsettings', '2022-09-01').properties
    appSettings: {
      'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION': '~4'
      'WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG': '1'
      alwaysOn: true
    }
    appName: functionAppName
  }
}

resource slot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2016-08-01' = {
  name: 'slot'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  parent: function
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    httpsOnly: true
    enabled: true
    alwaysOn: true
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_ADD_SITENAME_BINDINGS_IN_APPHOST_CONFIG'
          value: 1
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
          value: service_func_package
        }
        //Access to ServiceBus via Managed Identity
        {
          name: 'ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace'
          value: '<ServiceBusUrl>'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'ApplicationDataStorage'
          value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};AccountKey=${storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value}'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: applicationInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'dotnet'
        }
        {
          name: 'SCALE_CONTROLLER_LOGGING_ENABLED'
          value: 'AppInsights:Verbose'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_PRESERVE_DEFAULT_STICKY_SLOT_SETTINGS'
          value: 'false'
        }
      ]
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
    }
  }
}
```

### appendAppsettings Module:

```
param currentAppSettings object 
param appSettings object
param appName string

resource siteconfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2020-12-01' = {
  name: '${appName}/appSettings'
  properties: union(currentAppSettings, appSettings)
}
```

### Function code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ServiceBusFunctions
{
    public class ServiceBusReceiver
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ServiceBusReceiver> _logger;

        public ServiceBusReceiver(ILogger<ServiceBusReceiver> log)
        {
            _logger = log;
        }

        [FunctionName("ServiceBusReceiver")]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("functionslottestpfh-topic", "functionslottestpfh-subs", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string mySbMsg)
        {
            await Task.Delay(300000);
            _logger.LogInformation("Received");
        }
    }
}
```

### Pipeline:

The pipeline just triggers a start slot, resource deployment, switch slot and stop slot via Powershell

Comment: You might want to elaborate on the _at-most-once_ processing and messaging where you have no control over the consumers during the deployment time.

Comment: Sorry for the rather stupid question, however is Azure Function SDK not Peek Lock only? Due to a very tight schedule we cannot afford rewriting everything